# Cursor appears before customized UITextField background image

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have a background image of size 360X44 which I am trying to put as the background of my UITextFields however it is showing an unexpected behaviour. The cursor is getting appeared before the image starts but the texts getting written on the write place.

[image: image of the background]

**Implementation of my UiTextField**

```
UITextField *textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 75, 215, 30)];
textFieldRounded.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
UIImage *fieldBGImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"textfield_normal.png"]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:50 topCapHeight:50];
[textFieldRounded setBackground:fieldBGImage];
textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
textFieldRounded.placeholder = @"http://";  //place holder
textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textFieldRounded.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;    
[self.view addSubview:textFieldRounded];    
textFieldRounded.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 4):

i just set TextFiled background Image like my bellow code And working Good:-

```
        [YourTextFiled setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
        YourTextFiled.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        YourTextFiled.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 12, 20)];
        YourTextFiled.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        YourTextFiled.background = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"xFOEr.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:17];
```

looking like"-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest instead of adding image as a background color. Add it as a different component. i.e. First add a `UIImageView` and then add your `UITextField` on it.

In the mean time try to make this change in your current code :

```
UITextField *textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 75, 360, 44)];
```

Comment: I tried expanding it to 360X44 with no success. how would I do it then with UITextField over UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: window.frame];
textView.text = @"text\n text\n text";
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage.jpg"];
[textView addSubview: imgView];
[textView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
[window addSubview: textView];
```

Dont use background property. Add image as subview and send subview to back.